# Magento 2 cannot view after install

Tags: magento2, installation

I have installed magento2 in fedora 23.

```
 Your Store Address:
      http://magento2xxxxxxxx.com/
 Magento Admin Address:
      http://magento2xxxxxxxx.com/admin/
```

After install I load this URL Browser says Domain not found Problem both front end and admin page.

I give a permission:

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento2/
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/magento2/
```

Suggest me How to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a server configuration problem and not a Magento issue.

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism Magento setup is now off-topic? We should be asking clarifying questions before starting close-parades.

Comment: @philwinkle "Domain not found" clearly sounds like misconfigured hosts I assumed that it was off topic

Comment: Closing with "server configuration problem" is not helpful. Redirecting them to community.magento.com or explaining the reasons why this error may occur, is. Arjun's answer below is a good example of this.

Answer (score 1):

I had these problem in ubuntu. You may try out these steps.

For **front end**

Move to directory install magento2. Use command in terminal:

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`.

For **admin side**:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride  all
</Directory>`
```

was not present in the end of file /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf before `</VirtualHost>`. Also make sure that mod_rewrite is enable by entering command:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```